# Async tableview update in swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous

What if i put my updater in viewWillAppear using dispatch_async? I don't know... it seems too simple. I can't understand this because in c# after my threads i used .Abort(). What about swift? Will my thread aborted after runtime?

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
  {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

        self.data = []

        //some code with update

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend something along these lines:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    updateData()
}

func updateData() {

    makeAsyncCall{ (data) -> () in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.data = []
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }

}

func makeAsyncCall(completion: ([DataType]) -> ()) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

        /* do data update */
        completion(data)
    }
}
```

It better breaks up the functionality, and as far as I know (untested) it shouldn't have any issues.